# Create mysql dump file, how to edit for WordPress site migration

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I've spent over a day on this. Am a bit stuck!

I think I understand how to create the dump file using PHPMYADMIN. Then, I need to edit it to change URL to new site, in this case, a local path on my computer. I then import the edited file into the database at the new location.

I am getting some of the data on the new site location; some links, some text, no images however. But the new site location is broken: getting php header errors, so it's not working. I then restore the database on the new location, so this proves I can import a database, so I think I am not clear on edited the database dump file.

I'm am fuzzy on exactly how to edit the dump file. I have globally changed URL's. But I don't know if there is a "home" path or "absolute" path I need to change. I have read tons of info on the web, watched some videos too.

BTW: I am runngin XAMPPLITE on my local machine, under the "desktop" server software package - thus running Apache and MySQL on local machine.

As I said, I have read a lot online about WordPress migration. I know there are some plugin's but I would rather do this manually, if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not an expert on the wordpress side of things, but if you are interested in moving the database over, I would use the mysql dump commands directly (rather than trying to get PHP to do it for you).  It is literally one command to dump, and one command to import.  The dump file itself is a textfile containing the mysql syntax to recreate the table(s) from scratch on a new database, so a find and replace would likely work if you know exactly what your new and old root paths are.  Hope that helps a little :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out not to be terribly difficult.  I was able to successfully clone a live site onto my development system with one small SQL statement.  [See this WordPress document.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Running_a_Development_Copy_of_WordPress)

Hope this helps.